# how the    xsl title 

Tags: xslt

xml

```
<data>The production of opium itself has basically not changed since ancient times...Opium trade became more regular by the seventeenth century, when it was mixed with tobacco for smoking, and addiction was first recognized... This is a test Message3...This is showing off a handful of updates to its line of audio accessories this week at IFA in Berlin. At top of the list is the newly revealed inAir 5000, a hefty tabletop AirPlay speaker that the company is firmly positioning to take on Bowers&Wilkins' Zeppelin line (which also recently got its own AirPlay version)... Like that system, the inAir certainly offers a unique take on aesthetics, with a teardrop design. The company opted not to install an Apple dock on the 110 watt system, given that compatible devices can stream audio wirelessly to the thing via AirPlay...
</data>
```

I need to added paragraph for each sentence after ... in xsl, and paragraph needs to be  more than 1 line.

xml

```
             I need to write XSL for the above xml to get the out like this.
```

The production of opium itself has basically not changed since ancient times. Opium trade became more regular by the seventeenth century, when it was mixed with tobacco for smoking, and addiction was first recognized. This is a test Message3.

```
              <p>This is showing off a handful of updates to its line of audio accessories this week at IFA in Berlin. At top of the list is the newly revealed inAir 5000, a hefty tabletop AirPlay speaker that the company is firmly positioning to take on Bowers&Wilkins' Zeppelin line (which also recently got its own AirPlay version).</p>
              <p>Like that system, the inAir certainly offers a unique take on aesthetics, with a teardrop design. The company opted not to install an Apple dock on the 110 watt system, given that compatible devices can stream audio wirelessly to the thing via AirPlay.</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add paragraph"?  Edit your post to show the desired output.

Comment: XML

 <data>This is a test message.This is a test message.This is a test message.
      This is a test message.This is a test message.This is a test message.
      This is a test message.This is a test message.This is a test message.
    </data>


I need to write XSL for the above xml to get the out like this, so dynamically i need to add <p></p>  tag  between each sentence.

    <p>This is a test message.</p>
    <p>This is a test message.</p>
    <p>This is a test message.</p>
    <p>This is a test message.</p>
    <p>This is a test message.</p>
    <p>This is a test message.</p>

Comment: Your XML is no longer valid because of the & in there. Do you mean to use &amp;chocolate?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? It uses a recursive template to look for periods in the text. It places the text up to the first period in a HTML paragraph tag, and then recursively calls the template for the text after the period.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html"/>
   <xsl:template match="/data">
      <xsl:call-template name="paragraph">
         <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text()"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="'...'"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'.'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template name="paragraph">
      <xsl:param name="text"/>
      <xsl:param name="separator"/>
      <xsl:param name="replace"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="contains($text,$separator)">
            <xsl:variable name="firsttext" select="normalize-space(substring-before($text,$separator))"/>
            <xsl:if test="string-length($firsttext) &gt; 0">
               <p>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$firsttext"/>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$replace"/>
               </p>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:call-template name="paragraph">
               <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(substring-after($text,$separator))"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="string-length($text) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$replace"/>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces the following output:

```
<p>This is showing off a handful of updates to its line of audio accessories this week at IFA in Berlin. At top of the list is the newly revealed inAir 5000, a hefty tabletop AirPlay speaker that the company is firmly positioning to take on Bowers&amp;Wilkins' Zeppelin line (which also recently got its own AirPlay version).</p>
<p>Like that system, the inAir certainly offers a unique take on aesthetics, with a teardrop design. The company opted not to install an Apple dock on the 110 watt system, given that compatible devices can stream audio wirelessly to the thing via AirPlay.</p>
```

Note that your current input XML is not valid, because of the & in there. I have assumed you mean to do &

If you were looking for solely text output though, and not HTML paragraph tags, you could replace the creation of the **p** elements in the first **xsl:when** with this code instead.

```
   <xsl:value-of select="$firsttext" />
   <xsl:value-of select="$replace"/>
   <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
```

When you do this, the output is as follows:

```
This is showing off a handful of updates to its line of audio accessories this week at IFA in Berlin. At top of the list is the newly revealed inAir 5000, a hefty tabletop AirPlay speaker that the company is firmly positioning to take on Bowers&amp;Wilkins' Zeppelin line (which also recently got its own AirPlay version).

Like that system, the inAir certainly offers a unique take on aesthetics, with a teardrop design. The company opted not to install an Apple dock on the 110 watt system, given that compatible devices can stream audio wirelessly to the thing via AirPlay.
```

Comment: @_Tim C: This solution would be good had you not missed the period characters.

Comment: i have tried your solution which you have provided and i have not getting the output as "<p>This is a test message</p>
<p>This is a test message</p>
<p>This is a test message</p>
<p>This is a test message</p>
<p>This is a test message</p>
<p>This is a test message</p>
<p>This is a test message</p>
<p>This is a test message</p>
<p>This is a test message</p>"

Comment: @_Dimitre Novatchev Ah yes, I see. I have amended my XSLT to include the periods at the end of each line. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I've made a change to cope with ..., but your input XML is no long valid XML because &Chocolate is not a recognised entity. Do you mean &amp;chocolate? Also, please be wary of changing your requirements after the question has been answered. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. i Need to handle any of the special characters which contains in the xml. Please i am extremely sorry about changing the requirement. can you please help me out handling special characters which contains in the xml feed.

Comment: @user926230: Not a problem, as it wasn't a big change in this case. However, your input XML is no longer valid XML because of the unknown &Chocolate entity. You will need to correct this before proceeding.

Comment: In my xml feed it contains "&" also.

Comment: I have changed the XSLT to split solely on '...', and leave single periods untouched. Your input XML is still not valid. It it contains a single "&" which has not been 'escaped'. I would expect it to be "&amp;". Until it is valid XML, you won't be able to use XSLT on it.

Comment: how to handle the "&" because my xml is having & symbol.

Comment: @user you should preprocess your xml and escape "&" with `&amp;` or using CDATA.

Comment: How we can do using tokenize method same process please help me out.

Comment: @user926230, this is not the place to ask follow-up questions. Either edit your question to clarify, visit [chat], or ask a new question.

Comment: I need to added paragraph for each sentence after ... in xsl, and paragraph needs to be  more than 1 line. Paragraph needs to be 3 lines. not just one line. Please help me out.